# Altering comment data on publishing

Tags: 8

I have a boolean field ( field_rejected ) in my custom comment implementation ,I need to set this field to false if this comment is published

I tried hook_comment_update and hook_comment_insert, This didn't work as it says in the documentation :

> "Note that hook implementations may not alter the stored entity data."

Then I tried doing this using hook_entity_presave but this also didn't work as it results in an infinite loading or error code 500.

This is the code I used:

```
function custom_comments_notification_comment_presave($comment) {
  if ($comment->isPublished() && !$comment->original->isPublished()) {
    $comment->set('field_rejected', 0, $notify = true);
    $comment->save();
  }
}
```

Note that this is implemented in custom module's .module file.

How can I solve this? How can change the boolean 'field_rejected' after publishing a comment?

Comment: remove that $comment->save();
Because you are already in the save process and you will trigger it over and over again with this.
And use FALSE instead of 0.

Comment: Thanks!!, i removed the $comment->save(); and it worked !! the 0 also works as a FALSE

Comment: Yes that was just a suggestion imho it looks a bit better :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove that $comment->save(); Because you are already in the save process and you will trigger it over and over again with this.

Answer (score 0):

`$comment->save();` should not be there as a `save` will be done automatically
(you are in a `_presave` hook)